# TortioiseGit - Trouble creating a local repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm trying to get a local git repository running on my machine using tortoisegit, but I've been unable to do so.

I've installed the latest version of msysgit (fullinstall 1.6.4), and the latest version of tortoisegit 0.9.1.0-32bit. I also running a relatively fresh install of winXp, so I doubt it's some sort of conflict.

I have also rebooted, and updated the tortoisegit settings to point to the msysgit bin directory.

When I try to create a new local repository using tortoisegit I get a blank error dialog labeled tortoisegit. I've also seen this dialog in the tortoisegit settings window.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msysGit-fullinstall is only needed if you want to *hack* on msysGit. For normal usage get the regular package, e.g. [Git-1.6.4-preview20090730.exe](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.6.4-preview20090730.exe).

Try running "git init" from a Git Bash and see if it works.